# Using Bot State Accessors Inside Dialogs

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm a few days in on the Bot Framework so very new. I've been trying to arrive at an understanding of managing the state and to be honest I'm just not getting it. It seems the framework and advice on this has changed a lot recently and there doesn't appear to be any clear advice or samples.

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) Says:

> Save the information to bot state. This would require you to design
>   your dialog to have access to the bot's state property accessors.

But there are no examples of how to achieve this.

The last step in one of my Waterfall dialogs looks like this:

```
AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
{
    var response = stepContext.Result as FoundChoice;
    stepContext.Values["maxPrice"] = response;

    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(SearchDialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);
});
```

It's basically kicking off a new dialog and I want to either pass the collected data from this dialog into the `SearchDialog` either by passing the object or, preferably, saving this into my `BotAccessors` and then the `SearchDialog` retrieving this and using it.

All MS examples have waterfall steps defined as `async` methods on the `IBot` class. Which also isn't how they recommend putting bot dialogs together making the example pretty useless all in all.

Also, it seems that even the Microsoft v4 docs are out of date, such as [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-persist-user-inputs?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), that is still telling us to use deprecated code, such as:

```
options.State.Add(new ConversationState(storage));
```

Unfortunately it seems the docs are more confusing than helpful on this topic at the moment.  What's the best way to manage this state?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: I've not moved back to looking into this yet. So far it seems that the default built in dialogs aren't designed with DI in mind at all which is unfortunate. Also the way dialog sets are built ahead of usage also makes DI problematic. Once I get more time to look into it I'll update this Q with an A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: The Basic Bot sample has been replaced by the Core Bot sample so this answer is outdated**

Have a look at the way a basic bot is set up either in the [samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/4.2.1-VSIX/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot) or by [creating a basic bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) from the template in Azure.

The state property accessor is declared in the [`BasicBot`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4.2.1-VSIX/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/BasicBot.cs#L35) class:

```
private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<GreetingState> _greetingStateAccessor;
```

It is then assigned to in the `BasicBot` [constructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4.2.1-VSIX/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/BasicBot.cs#L41):

```
_greetingStateAccessor = _userState.CreateProperty<GreetingState>(nameof(GreetingState));
```

It is then [passed](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4.2.1-VSIX/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/BasicBot.cs#L62) to the `GreetingDialog` constructor:

```
Dialogs.Add(new GreetingDialog(_greetingStateAccessor, loggerFactory));
```

It is then assigned to a property of the [`GreetingDialog`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4.2.1-VSIX/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/Dialogs/Greeting/GreetingDialog.cs) class:

```
UserProfileAccessor = userProfileStateAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userProfileStateAccessor));
```

It is then used in many places throughout the `GreetingDialog` class with the [`GetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.istatepropertyaccessor-1.getasync) and [`SetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.istatepropertyaccessor-1.setasync) methods. For example:

```
var greetingState = await UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => null);
```

Comment: Sure this is all standard farye but really, really doesn't lead itself to what I consider good practice or dependency injection. IoC a lá Mvvm is an approach I use for lots of types of projects. It seems very awkward to do this with dialogs.

Comment: Passing things manually like this is imho a bad thing to have to do. particularly in a .NET core app where DI and IoC have been made first class citizens finally.

Comment: That said, this post is a good example and is what I'm already doing.

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to submit design suggestions to the GitHub repos?

Comment: I would. And will do when I have gotten more experience with the framework and time to think about it all. I'm too new to it all at the moment.

Comment: Would you consider this Stack Overflow question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Last two steps from Waterfall Dialog may look something like the following:

```
public async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskForLocation(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // the previous step asked for the Email so now bot is going to save it in botstate
        _state = await _accessor.GetAsync(sc.Context, () => new MyApplicationState());
        var email = _state.Email = (string)sc.Result;

        // this is not in the template because it is saving in a different manner
        // just being explicit about saving here
        await _accessor.SetAsync(sc.Context, _state);

        await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Got your email!");

        var prompt = new PromptOptions
        {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Please specify location."),
        };

        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(locationPrompt, prompt);
    }

    public async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinishDialog(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _state = await _accessor.GetAsync(sc.Context);
        _state.Location = (string)sc.Result;

        // save location this time
        await _accessor.SetAsync(sc.Context, _state);

        await sc.Context.SendActivityAsync("Got your location!");

        return await sc.EndDialogAsync();
    }
```

If you exited the dialog above, and assuming you implemented [StateBotAccessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and are using UserProfile property then you retrieve it by:

```
    var _state = await stateBotAccessors.UserState.UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(context);
```

Or if you wanted to pass it from a child dialog, you can end with:

```
    return await sc.EndDialogAsync(_state);
```

Comment: Actually, my questions was more around how to get the BotAccessors into a dialog. It seems that using DI is quite awkward in the BotFramework.

Comment: In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp check out "Configure your bot" which tackles how to set it up in Startup.cs. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: What does DI stand for?

Comment: I think he means Dependency Injection

Comment: Indeed I do mean DI.